# Valum's Ajax JQuery File Uploader Progress Slows Down Browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to implement an Ajax JQuery File Upload Utility found [here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader). Everything works excellent except one small problem. When I select multiple files for upload, the whole process slows down the browser behavior including other browser tabs.

I suspect this could be due to the number of progress events fired. Is there any solution for this. One I could think of is to restrict parallel uploads so that files are uploaded one by one.

Can anyone suggest a good work around?

Comment: There must be something else causing the problem. I have used that uploader many times in the past and never had slow downs.

Comment: check the speed and number of dom elements of the page with yahoo yslow firebug extension and find the culprit.

Comment: @slash197 Can you tell how do I instruct it to upload files one by one

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileUploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    multiple: false
});
```

Comment: I guess this would restrict from selecting multiple files. That's not exactly what I want. I need some way so that the upload (of any number of files) to happen one by one (even after selecting multiple files)

Comment: There is no such feature. You would have to write that yourself, use `onSubmit` to stop sending files to the server if there's another process and `onComplete` to resume sending other files

Comment: Good suggestion. I would try this and get back here. Thank you